# How can I prevent the \listof command from the float package scrambling my headers?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, header-footer, minted

I'm using the `minted` package, which uses the `float` package. When I add the 'List of Listings' in my thesis, the `\listoflistings` command calls the `\listof`command from the `float` package.

My problem is that this command modifies the headings of subsequent pages, and shows 'LIST OF LISTINGS' in the header of the following pages, up to my second chapter. How can I prevent it from redefining the headers defined in my `.cls` file?

Comment: Why does it go up to your second chapter and not change with the first?

Comment: I don't know... I guess this is because my first chapter is only two pages.

Comment: Or because my first chapter is in fact a chapter*

Comment: That's it. When using `\chapter*`, no headings are set. So, the `\chapter*` chapters takes the headings of the previously set page style.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured out:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\float@listhead}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}{\def\@tempa{\section*}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\chapter*}}\@tempa{#1}}
\makeatother
```

And in bonus, [I learned a little bit more about LaTeX internals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do).

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm for me, my issue was with list of frames. Only difference is that I replaced the `#1` with `\centering\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase{#1}` t suit my needs. Thanks.